# is there a comparison between an oracle's CURSOR and a CTE (common table expression)

Tags: oracle

been googling and cant find anything that will explain PROS CONS of using a CTE vs a Cursor

Not sure if even a comparison might be possible.

Any info/enlightenment would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't really make sense.  It's a bit like asking about the pros and cons of an apple vs a toaster oven.  They're not generally comparable.

A cursor is a handle to a SQL statement executing on the database.  Every query generates a cursor (though depending on the code, that handle may or may not be exposed to the client application).  That query may or may not use a CTE.  Whether it uses a CTE has no relationship to whether a cursor is created or whether the cursor is exposed to the client application.

You could sensibly ask whether, say, it makes sense to use a CTE rather than, say, an inline view.  But the answer to that question is likely going to be rather vague because it'll come down to a somewhat vague and subjective criteria of what approach most clearly describes the results you want and provides the best encapsulation of the different elements of the query.